# Which process will get in the ready queue first if they get ready at the same time?

Tags: process, operating-system, scheduling

Assuming now I have two processes: process A is running, and process B is waiting for I/O finished.

At the k CPU tick-mark, process B receive a signal that the I/O is finished, and at the same time, process A called fork to created a new process C.

In this situation, which one will get into the ready queue first, process B or process C?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are in a single processor system (and the question does not make sense in a multi-processor system), nothing occurs at the same time.

If B's I/O completes, it will trigger an interrupt that will be responded to by whatever process happens to be running at the moment. The interrupt handler will make B runnable then return to the process that was running.

There really is no way to predict under the conditions you have set forth who gets in the queue first.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. This question should be closed as its too board/low quality.